# jade nodejs equivalent of php inline scripting

Tags: php, node.js, express, pug

I'm having a serious trouble trying to discover how to do a certain thing that **i don't know how to name/describe it correctly** in nodejs, I've learned **some** concepts and basics of nodejs and i'm already messing up with express and jade but i stll can't figure out what's the equivalent of this on a .jade file, ignore the html markup. ( What i'm aiming to do is printing the results of a sql fetch )

```
<body>
<p><? print "Hello World"; ?></p>
</body>
```

My app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render('page.jade', {
       title: 'My Page' 
    });
});

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});
```

PS: I'm sorry if my question is too mediocre, I've searched but could't find anything that helped me.

Comment: Nodejs is different than PHP

Comment: @true I think the poster is familiar with PHP and would like to do the equivalent in Node.js, but the question is indeed misleading and the example is way too general, of course.

Comment: @true Oh i know that, but my question is just how to print something inside the jade file using variables defined for example in my app.js

Comment: I worked few weeks with NodeJs during my thesis, maybe you'll find that useful. Using tags like `<% title %>` on the `page` you will display correctly, for instance, the title you assigned in the app.js to `page`. With this solution you can use a simple html file instead of Jade. Hope it's a good starting point and that I didn't missed the point of your question

Comment: Have you seen the jade language documentation for code? http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/

Comment: @Markviduka that looks like a different template engine, maybe EJS? (https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs). This question is specifically about the Jade template engine (http://jade-lang.com/)

Comment: @Codesleuth yes but i don't exactly know how that can help me, please bear with my stupidity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any object you pass with render gets passed into the view, which would be your jade file. You can then render the object property using `=` after the tag or `#{}` inline.

```
res.render('page', {
   title: 'My Page',
   name: 'Ben'
});
```

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        p My name is #{name}
```

Output would be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>My name is Ben</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the only way i can pass "information" from my nodejs app file to the .jade one?

Comment: You could also setup a route to send JSON and retrieve it using AJAX, or you could use websockets.

Comment: @Boots I strongly recommend that you embrace this methodology, rather than trying to stick with the old PHP ways. Having server side code embedded into the markup (eg. `<? print "Hello World"; ?>`) is widely accepted as poor design. It's far better to pass only the data through to the view, as Ben Fortune demonstrates here.

Comment: @MattDavey Thanks! i'm thinking that i still don't really understand most of the nodejs concept, because i'm not trying to "stick with the old ways" i'm just trying to understand how i can "show" information generated from the nodejs file ( i.e results of a mysql fetch ) to the client view.

Comment: @Boots ah I see, so in Bens example, 'Ben' is hard coded into the view data. It doesn't need to be hard coded, it can also come from some intermediate variable eg. `var myData = getSomeDataFromMySql(); res.render('page', { title: 'My Page', name: myData })`

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answers, you can also do if/else statements in your jade file

App/Router

```
res.render('view',{
    "error": "ExampleError!"
});
```

View

```
if error
    p An error occurred: #{error}
else
    p All is well
```

Output

```
<p>An error occurred: ExampleError!</p>
```